# Which Disney film reused the most animation from previous films?

Tags: production, animation, disney

We know [Disney often reused animation from previous films](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/115421/9382). I'm curious to learn if the practice for worse over time, or that did perhaps faded away.

**Do we know which film reused the most animation?**

---

*I can think of several ways to measure this by, the main two being the absolute length of reused animation, and reused animation as a percentage of the overall running time of the film it was reused in. Those two are what I'm interested in, but I'm open to other interesting metrics.*

Comment: I think that whilst the linked question had a certain amount of *"OMG! Did they really do that?"* to keep it open, this is just trivia.

Comment: @tesujin relevant metas: [The term "trivia" is just lazy. Can't we do better?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4514/1074), [How to judge ahead of time if people will think my question is "movie trivia" and perhaps unsuitable for the site?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4738/1074) and [Can we please redefine "trivia"?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1809/1074).

Comment: Given the above metas I don't think this is obviously trivia.

Comment: Perhaps I could flesh out the question a bit. I tried to when asking, but it really boils down to the bare question. I'm interested in learning if the practice for worse over time, or rather faded away.

Comment: As this has been attributed to just one of Disney's directors, Wolfgang Reitherman, one could say that it started when he began directing & ended when he stopped.

Comment: *Do we know which film reused the most animation?* For that to know the total time of reused material is not enough. You must know how the reused pieces are distributed over all his movies.